# Dividends Growing Faster than Cost of Capital

Tags: calculation, stock-valuation

If a share's dividends are assumed to be indefinitely growing faster than the cost of capital (discount rate) then the net present value of all future dividends for the share can be shown to be infinite.

What alternative methods are there for valuing such a share other than the net present value method which clearly falls short in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the method falls short, it's the premise that is wrong.

If the dividend stream really did grow faster than the cost of capital indefinitely, eventually the company behind the share would become larger than the entire economy. Logically, at some point, the growth must slow down.

Comment: This is incorrect.  There is no rule that the cost of capital must always exceed the maximum expected long term growth of every company in a market.  It is certainly possible for several companies to have indefinite growth beyond the cost of capital (without invoking a restrictive no arbitrage assumption).